# 配列の要素のあるなしでデータベースへの登録を分けたい

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

商品情報の配列のcodeの要素のあるなしでデータベースへの登録を分けたいです。
しかし、クラスかコントローラのどちらにどのような記述をすればいいのかわかりません。
CSVReader　クラスに

```
package drinkMachine.csv;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class CSVReader {
    private String fileName;
    private Integer num;
    public void csvAdd(HttpServletRequest request, ServletContext con)

    {

        // サーブレットファイルアップロードオブジェクトを生成
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        // 基準値
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1024);
        upload.setSizeMax(-1);
        upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");
        // try catch 必要あり？
        List<FileItem> fileList;
        try {
            fileList = upload.parseRequest(request);
            System.out.println("fileList" + fileList);

            for (FileItem uploadItem : fileList) {

                // isFormFieldはフォームデータであるかの真偽を返す。fileならFalse
                if (!(uploadItem.isFormField())) {

                    // ファイルデータのファイル名(PATH名含む)
                    fileName = uploadItem.getName();

                    if ((fileName != null) && (!fileName.equals(""))
                            && fileName.matches(".+\\.(csv)$")) {
                        // PATH名を除くファイル名を取得
                        fileName = (new File(fileName)).getName();

                        // ファイルを格納するフォルダのパス
                        String path = "C:\\pleiades\\workspace\\jspServlet\\WebContent\\csv";

                        // ファイルデータを指定されたファイルに書き出し
                        try {
                            uploadItem.write(new File(path + fileName));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // fileの名前は(パスは)プログラム内で使うため受け取る
                        // image はname属性
                        if (uploadItem.getFieldName().equals("csv")) {
                            String file = path + "\\" + fileName;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e1) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<List<String>> read() {

        // 返却用リスト箱作成
        List<List<String>> ret = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        if (fileName != null) {
            System.out.println("fileName" + fileName);
            String inputCsvFile = "C:\\pleiades\\workspace\\jspServlet\\WebContent\\csv\\test1.csv";

            File csv = new File(inputCsvFile);
            System.out.println(csv);

            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                int lineCount = 0;
                // ファイルオープン
                 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));

                // num行読み込む（0の場合は全行）
                String line = "";
                int idx = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    lineCount++;

                    // 1行を格納する箱作成
                    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // 文字列index
                    int idxFrom = 0;
                    int idxTo = 0;
                    // 文字列長
                    while (true) {

                        // 最終項目を取得後は終了
                        if (idxFrom > line.length()) {
                            break;
                        }

                        // 次のセパレータ位置を取得
                        idxTo = line.indexOf(",", idxFrom);

                        // セパレータが発見できない場合は最終項目を取得
                        if (idxTo == -1) {
                            idxTo = line.length();
                        }

                        // 文字列取得
                        String word = line.substring(idxFrom, idxTo);

                        // 文字列を格納
                        tmpList.add(word);

                        // 検索開始位置を更新
                        idxFrom = idxTo + 1;
                    }

                    // 返却用リストに1行データを格納
                    ret.add(tmpList);

                    // カウンタ
                    if (idx % 1000 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("入力: " + idx + " 件");
                    }
                    idx++;

                    // numを超えたら読み込み終了。numが0のときは全量読む。
                    if (lineCount != 0 && idx > lineCount) {

                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null) {
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

と書きreturn retで何個かCSVファイルに記載されている商品データの配列（例えば、[1(code),100(price),apple(name)])をそれぞれ取得することができました。
CsvUpdateControllerには

```
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CSVReader csvReading;
        String fileName;
        ServletContext con = getServletConfig().getServletContext();

        csvReading = new CSVReader();
        csvReading.csvAdd(request,con);
        List<List<String>> csvResult = csvReading.read();

        System.out.println("csvResult"+csvResult);
    }

}
```

Dao　クラスには

```
package drinkMachine.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import drinkMachine.beans.ItemBean;

public class T001ItemDao {
    private Connection conn = null;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    public T001ItemDao() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "XXX",
                "xxx", "xxx");
    }

    // 商品登録メソッド
    public int addItem(String name, String price, String count,String isPR) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            String query = "INSERT INTO T001_ITEM" + "(ITEM_NO,ITEM_NM,UNIT_PRICE,STOCK_COUNT,RECORD_DATE,IS_PR)" +"VALUES(TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'"+ name +"','"+ price +"','"+ count +"', sysdate,'"+ isPR +"')";
            System.out.println(query);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return result;

    }

    public String checkAdd(String name) {

        // Dataの重複チェック
        String kensaku = "";
        try {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT count(*) as checkItem" + " FROM T001_ITEM"
                    + " WHERE ITEM_NM ='" + name + "'";
            kensaku = "";
            System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            resultSet.next();

            kensaku = resultSet.getString("checkItem");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(kensaku);
        return kensaku;
    }

    //引数：商品コード、商品名、金額、数量
    //戻り値：結果更新できたか否か　YES　or　NO
    public int update(String code,String name,String price,String count) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "UPDATE T001_ITEM SET"
                    + " ITEM_NM ='" + name + "',"  +
                    " UNIT_PRICE = '" + price + "', " +
                    " STOCK_COUNT = '" + count + "'," +
                    " RECORD_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"+
                    " WHERE ITEM_NO = " + code;

          result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }catch (SQLException e){
          System.out.println("SQLException:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }


public ItemBean getLineItems(String code){
    String sql = "SELECT ITEM_NO,ITEM_NM,UNIT_PRICE,STOCK_COUNT FROM T001_ITEM WHERE ITEM_NO  ='" + code + "'";
    ItemBean ItemInfo = new ItemBean();

    try {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        resultSet.next();

        ItemInfo.setCode(resultSet.getString("ITEM_NO"));
        ItemInfo.setName(resultSet.getString("ITEM_NM"));
        ItemInfo.setPrice(resultSet.getString("UNIT_PRICE"));
        ItemInfo.setCount(resultSet.getString("STOCK_COUNT"));



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return ItemInfo;
}
}
```

と書きました。
登録にはaddItem　を、更新にはupdate　メソットを使います。
その商品情報のcodeがあれば、Daoクラスに記載しているUPDATE文を呼び出し、codeがなければDaoクラスに記載しているINSERT文を呼び出したいです。
そのようなことを行いたいなら、配列名[0]のように指定しif文であるなしを分岐させたら良いのでしょうか？
また、何個も商品の配列（例えば、[1,100,apple],[2,300,orange],[,500.banana]など）リストの中に何個もの配列が入っている時、それぞれの配列がcodeを持つか持たないかで呼び出すSQL文を変えたい時どのように書けばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: Daoクラスを記載して貰わないと、HQLを使っているのかCriteriaを使っているのか分からないので追記した方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: stack overflowはQ&Aを蓄積するサイトです。用が済んだからと言って質問文を削除してはいけません。

Answer (score 2):

CSVの仕様にもよると思います。
もしcodeなしがCSVに表現されるなら、読み込み時に単純に空文字になると思うので、質問に記載されたコードの場合、Listの先頭が空文字だとINSERTするメソッドを実行する、といった分岐になると思います。
もしcodeなしがCSVに表現されない（カラムが省略されて読み込むカラム数が減る）場合、Listのsizeで判定するようになると思います。
もしカラム数がレコードによってバラつく場合、これはCSVの仕様でカラム数をそろえてもらう必要があると思います。

ちなみに、上記質問ではカンマの位置を調べてカンマ区切りでListにaddするように実装されていますが、Stringメソッドを使うともっと簡単に実装できます。

```
String str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd";
String[] strArray = str.split(",");
/* strArrayの中身は["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]となります */
```

参考まで。